# Clarke Wright Looping Issue

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to implement the Clarke Wright algorithm. The problem I seem to be having is that it merges lots of routes regardless of the tests I've put into place. I've been staring at this for a long time, so I thought it may help to cast a fresh pair of eyes over it.

Instead of creating routes that are valid (ie, the van has enough space to carry everything), it wildly creates routes everywhere regardless of whether it's got the capacity or not.

```
public void CWVRSolution(){
    List<SavingsNode> savings = new ArrayList<SavingsNode>();
    //  ArrayList<List<Customer>> routes = new ArrayList<List<Customer>>();
    this.soln = new ArrayList<List<Customer>>();
    //ArrayList<List<Customer>> routelist = new ArrayList<List<Customer>>();


    for (int i=0; i < prob.customers.size(); i++){
        for (int j=i+1; j<prob.customers.size();j++){
            if (i != j){
                double savingVal = (prob.depot.distance(prob.customers.get(i)) + prob.depot.distance(prob.customers.get(j))) - prob.customers.get(i).distance(prob.customers.get(j));                       
                savings.add(new SavingsNode(prob.customers.get(i),prob.customers.get(j),savingVal));
            }       
        }
    }   
    Collections.sort(savings);
    Collections.reverse(savings);


    int sncounter = 0;
    for (SavingsNode sn: savings ){

        // for every route in prob.soln
        // if from or to isnt in any of those routes
        // do that stuff

        if (!soln.contains(sn.i)){
            if(!soln.contains(sn.j)){
                if ((sn.i.c + sn.j.c) <= 50){
                    ArrayList<Customer> route = new ArrayList<Customer>();
                    route.add(sn.i);
                    route.add(sn.j);
                    soln.add(route);

                }
            }

        }else if(!soln.contains(sn.j)){
            //find a route that ends in from
            int d = 0;
            int e = 0;
            for (List<Customer> c: soln){
                for (Customer x : c){
                    d += x.c;
                }
                if (c.get(c.size()-1) == sn.i){
                    if (d + sn.j.c <= 50){
                        //  Customer route = new Customer(sn.i.c, sn.j.c, cust.requirement);
                        ArrayList<Customer> newRoute = new ArrayList<Customer>();
                        newRoute.add(sn.i);

                        //  prob.customers.remove(sn.j);
                        //  soln.remove(c);
                        c.addAll(newRoute);
                        soln.add(c);
                        d=0;
                        //newRoute.clear();
                        break;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }


        if (!soln.contains(sn.i)){
            int d = 0;
            int e = 0;
            for (List<Customer> c:soln){
                if (c.get(0) == sn.j){
                    for (Customer x : c){
                        d += x.c;
                    }

                    if (d+ sn.i.c <= 50){
                        ArrayList<Customer> newRoute = new ArrayList<Customer>();
                        newRoute.add(sn.j);
                        soln.remove(c);
                        c.addAll(0, newRoute);
                        soln.add(c);
                        d=0;
                        //  soln.remove(arg0)
                        break;
                    }
                }   
            }       
        }

        List<Customer> merged = null;
        int mergescounter = 0;
        int xreq= 0;
        int yreq = 0;


        for (List<Customer> routeX: soln){
            if (merged != null){
                break;
            }
            if (routeX.get(routeX.size()-1)  == sn.i){
                for(Customer c:routeX){
                    xreq += c.c;
                }
                for (List<Customer> routeY: soln){
                    if (routeY.get(0) == sn.j){
                        for(Customer c:routeY){
                            yreq += c.c;
                        }
                        if ((routeX!=null)&&(routeY!=null)){
                            if (routeX != routeY){
                                int capnec = 0;
                                capnec = yreq+xreq;
                                if (sn.i.c +sn.j.c + capnec <= 50){
                                    List<Customer> merged1 = new ArrayList<Customer>();

                                    merged1.addAll(routeY);
                                    merged1.addAll(routeX);
                                    //  route.add(merged1);
                                    soln.add(merged1);
                                    mergescounter++;
                                    merged = routeX;
                                    capnec=0;
                                    break;

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
        if (merged!=null){
            soln.remove(merged);
        }
 }
```

Customer class:

```
public class Customer extends Point2D.Double{

// Requirements of the customer (number to be delivered)
public static int c;
public int requirement;
public Customer(int x, int y, int requirement){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    //parcel requirement
    this.c = requirement;
}
```

SavingsNode class

```
SavingsNode(Customer i, Customer j, double savingVal){
    this.i = i;
    this.j= j;
    this.savingVal = savingVal;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there some lines of code missing? At least some closing brackets?

Comment: @UweAllner above, possibly, but it's fine in my JDE

Comment: That's fine for you and your JDE, but not so fine for trying to help you...

Comment: @UweAllner updated with classes used